how to find the lagrange form of remainder for the expansion of arctan x.
The precise task was to determine the finite series of $\arctan x$ with the Lagrange form of the remainder.
While going through the process, I tried to find any pattern in the successive derivatives but could not find any help. Additionally, I found the recursive relation between the derivatives, but that didn't help either.
When I checked the answer in the back, the remainder was in the form of $\sin^{n} \theta$,
in fact the remainder was $\: R_n =\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n}\sin^n \,(\cot^{-1} \theta x )\sin  
 (\cot^{-1} \theta x )$
I am totally dumbstruck regarding how that sin function is coming. Any hint will be highly appreciated. However I found a similar question that didn't help either.

Which book is this from?

@Moo it is from BC Das and BN Mukherjee - Differential calculus. I study in an Indian college and this was recommended there.

I posted an answer and that was hard to type! :-)

Problem: Expand $f(x) =\arctan(x)$ as a finite series in powers of $x$ with the remainder in Lagrange's form.
The book gives this as
$$f(x) =  f(0) + x f'(0) + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} f''(0) + \ldots +\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}f^{(n-1)}(0)+\dfrac{x^{n}}{(n)!}f^{(n)}(\theta x), ~\text{where}~0 \lt \theta \lt 1$$
For $f(x) = \arctan(x) = \tan^{-1}(x)$, the first several derivates are given by
$$f'(x) = \left\{\tan ^{-1}(x),\frac{1}{x^2+1},-\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2},\frac{6 x^2-2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3},-\frac{24 x \left(x^2-1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^4},\frac{24 \left(5 x^4-10 x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^5}\right\}$$
The derivatives evaluated at zero are
$$f'(0) = \{0,1,0,-2,0,24\}$$
We have
$$\begin{align} f(x) &= f(0) + x f'(0) + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} f''(0) + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} f'''(0) + \dfrac{x^4}{4!} f^{(iv)}(0) + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} f^{(v)}(0)+ \ldots + R_n(x) \\ f(x) &= x -\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}- \ldots + R_n(x) \end{align}$$
Next, we have to find the remainder $R_n(x)$ given by
$$\dfrac{x^{n}}{(n)!}f^{(n)}(\theta x), ~\text{where}~0 \lt \theta \lt 1$$
We will need some trig identities for substitutions during simplification steps
$$\cos(\theta) = \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\\  2 \sin(2 \theta) = 2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)\\ \sin(x + y) = \sin(x) \cos(y) + \cos(x) \sin(y) \\ \cot^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(x)$$
This requires finding a general expression for the $n^{th}-$derivate of $f(x)$.
We will label the $n^{th}-$ derivative as $y_1, y_2, \ldots y_n$.
$y = \arctan{x}  = \tan^{-1}(x) \implies x = \tan(y)$
$\begin{align} y_1 &= (-1)^0 \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2} \\ &= (-1)^0 \dfrac{1}{1 + \tan^2(y)} \\ &= (-1)^0 \cos^2(y) \\ &= (-1)^0 \sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \end{align}$
$${}$$
$\begin{align} y_2 &= 2 \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)(-y_1) \\ 
y_2 &= (-1)^1 1! \sin\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) \sin^2 \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\end{align}$
$${}$$
$\begin{align} y_3 &= (-1)^1 \left[\cos\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} -y \right)\right)(2)(-y_1) \sin^{2} \left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) + \sin\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) \left( \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)(-y_1) \right)\right] \\ y_3 &= (-1)^1 (2)(-y_1) \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\left( \cos\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} -y \right)\right)\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)+ \sin\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \right) \\ y_3 &= (-1)^2 2! \sin^{3}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \left( \sin\left(2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) +\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y \right) \\ y_3 &= (-1)^2 (2!)\sin^{3}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \sin\left(3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) \end{align}$
$${}$$
$\begin{align} y_4 &= (-1)^2 (2!)\left( 3 \sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)(-y_1)\sin\left(3\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) +\sin^{3}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \cos\left(3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right)(-3y_1) \right) \\ y_4 &= (-1)^2 (2!)(3)(-y_1)\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right) \left( \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)\sin\left(3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right) + \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \cos\left(3\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right)\right)  \\ y_4 &= (-1)^3(3!) \sin^{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\left( \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right)+3\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y\right) \right) \\ y_4 &= (-1)^3 (3!) \sin^{4}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\sin\left(4\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right)   \end{align}$
From this, we can now spot the pattern
$$y_n = (-1)^{(n-1)} (n-1)! \sin^{n}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\sin\left(n\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-y\right)\right)$$
Technically, you should prove this by induction to make sure it works.
Now, from our last identity above, we have
$$\dfrac{\pi}{2} - y = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(x)=\cot^{-1}(x) $$
Substituting everything into the remainder formula, we have
$$R_n(x) = \dfrac{(-1)^{(n-1)}x^n}{n} \sin^{n}\left(\cot^{-1}(\theta x)\right)\sin\left(n\left(\cot^{-1}(\theta x)\right)\right) \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
Another Approach: I will map out the steps. We can write
$y_1 = \dfrac{1}{2i} \left[ \dfrac{1}{x-i} - \dfrac{1}{x+i}\right]$
Develop the pattern
$$y_n = \dfrac{(-1)^{(n-1)} (n-1)!}{2 i}\left[ \dfrac{1}{(x-i)^n} - \dfrac{1}{(x+i)^n}\right]$$
Let $x = r \cos(\theta), y = 1 = r \sin(\theta), \theta = \tan\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$
Use DeMoivre's Theorem, simplify and conclude.
Note: You can see another alternate approach in the amazing paper The Higher Derivatives Of The Inverse Tangent Function and Rapidly Convergent BBP-Type Formulas For Pi by Kunle Adegoke and Olawanle Layeni
